# Convert Java Byte[] to VB.NET MemoryStream

Tags: java, android, vb.net, web-services, base64

We are developing an Android Application (Java) that reads an image, encode the bytes in base64 to send them over HTTP (via GET) to a WebService written in VB.NET.

On .NET side, they are using this :

```
Dim Pix As Image
Pix = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Tree.jpg")

Dim ms As New MemoryStream
Pix.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
Dim ImByte() As Byte = ms.GetBuffer
ms.Close()
```

Sounds great.

How can I pass the correct string to them to correctly decode the image from Java encoding (unsigned) to .NET decoding (signed)?

Many thanks
Nicolas.

Comment: Surely on the .NET side you'll need to Convert.FromBase64String() ? And base64 is language-agnostic... doesn't matter if Java or Javascript or VB or raw x86 was doing the encoding....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First mistake: you're using [`GetBuffer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx) which will potentially be too big. Use [`ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx) instead.

On the Java side, just use any Base64 decoder, such as the [Apache Commons Codec one](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html). Don't worry about the signedness of the bytes - Base64 effectively makes that a non-issue for you.

That's assuming the web service client doesn't perform this automatically for you, of course... if your web service "advertises" a byte array using base64, it may well just be automatic.

Side question: why bother loading the image as an image at all? Why not just use:

```
Dim ImByte() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\Users\...\Tree.jpg")
```

?